# Trouble compiling PostGIS on macOS due to missing headers and configuration files, specifically with PostgreSQL 16

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

**Question**:
I'm currently facing challenges while attempting to compile PostGIS 3.4.0 on macOS (version 12.0.1). The primary issue arises from missing headers and configuration files, particularly in conjunction with PostgreSQL 16. Here's the specific error message I encounter during the compilation process:

```
configure: error: Could not find header: json.h
```

Here's the breakdown of my setup:

- **Operating System**: macOS 12.7.3 Monterey
- **PostGIS Version**: 3.4.0
- **Dependencies**:

  - **proj**: Installed via Homebrew at `/usr/local/opt/proj`
  - **protobuf-c**: Installed via Homebrew at `/opt/homebrew/opt/protobuf-c`
  - **PostgreSQL 16**: Installed via Homebrew at `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@16/16.2_1`
  - **json-c**: Installed via Homebrew at `/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.17`
  - **sfcgal**: Installed via Homebrew at `/usr/local/Cellar/sfcgal/1.5.1_1`
  - **pcre**: Installed via Homebrew at `/opt/homebrew/opt/pcre`

Here are the steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

1. Installed json-c using Homebrew: `brew install json-c`
2. Specified the json-c directory in the configure command: `--with-jsondir=/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.17/include/json-c`
3. Set the `CFLAGS` environment variable to include the json-c directory: `export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/Cellar/json-c/0.17/include/json-c/"`
4. Attempted to specify the PostgreSQL 16 `pg_config` directory in the configure command: `--with-pgconfig=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@16/16.2_1/bin/pg_config`

Despite these efforts, I'm still encountering the same error message. I suspect there may be additional dependencies missing or an issue with the environment configuration, particularly concerning PostgreSQL 16 compatibility.

Could someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this compilation issue for PostGIS on macOS, particularly with respect to integrating with PostgreSQL 16? Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your assistance!

P.S. Already tried steps from this [StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149123/enable-postgis-extension-for-postgresql-16-on-mac-m2): on StackOverflow but I'm blocked at this step: `./configure --with-projdir=/opt/homebrew/opt/proj --with-protobufdir=/opt/homebrew/opt/protobuf-c --with-pgconfig=/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@16/bin/pg_config --with-jsondir=/opt/homebrew/opt/json-c --with-sfcgal=/opt/homebrew/opt/sfcgal/bin/sfcgal-config --with-pcredir=/opt/homebrew/opt/pcre "LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gettext/0.22.2/lib" "CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gettext/0.22.2/include"`

EDIT: Ultimately, it couldn't work. My Pgsql kept pointing to v14 instead of v16 due to the forced installation of pgsql@14 when downloading `postgis` in the first place. Perhaps because I am using an M1 Mac. Had to use the following method which I recommend for M1 Mac users: [LEARN how to setup POSTGRESQL / POSTGIS and PgAdmin4 on DOCKER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p59ypKD4e_A)

Comment: Looks to me like an issue of installing the library but not the corresponding development package. Might also take a look at [Linking to json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c?tab=readme-ov-file#linking).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately, installing the library and its corresponding development package did not resolve the issue. In fact, I had already done that. I also reviewed the linking process to json-c, but the problem persists. Any further insights or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Update your question text with the revised build script you attempted.

Comment: It is difficult to build PostGIS from source because it needs so many libraries.

Comment: Did you check out https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html? Or you are not able to upgrade to OSX 10.13

Comment: shared updated build script @AdrianKlaver

Comment: That does not include the LDFLAGS and CFLAGS shown in the [Linking to json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c?tab=readme-ov-file#linking) page.

Comment: Should have added to previous comment the bottom line is that the `configure` cannot find the header file `json.h`. You need to determine whether it is indeed present and that you are pointing `configure` at it.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It was still not finding the header but deployed a manual header search ./configure CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/opt/json-c/include which finally got it to run. Now when I run make make install (final step!), I get the following error: /usr/local/include/postgresql@14/server/c.h:75:10: fatal error: 'libintl.h' file not found #include <libintl.h>          ^~~~~~~~~~~ 192 warnings and 1 error generated. make[1]: *** [lwgeom_geos.o] Error 1 make: *** [all] Error 1 I realize it's continuously referencing /postgresql@14/ despite my attemps. Any ideas?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver side bar: I have two different PostgreSQL instances on my computer because of the original dependency issues mostly with PostGIS.. a big part of why I've been having these issues

Comment: Looks to me like you are pointing at Postgres 14 version of `pg_config`. Look at the config.log to verify what you configured against.